# Residual Chi-Squares are not computed because of redundancies

Tags: logistic, chi-squared-test

I am using Logistic Regression to test the impact of a group of IV on a binary dependent V. I was not able to get the value of residual Chi squares. the error received in the output table is

"Residual Chi-Squares are not computed because of redundancies". Attached

can someone help on help on how to calculate residual chi-squares?
Thanks